# Integrate function with image $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: probability-theory, lebesgue-integral

I know that for any measure space $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mu)$ and any $\Sigma$-borel-measurble function $f\colon \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ the integral

$$\int_\Omega |f(x)| \, d\mu(x)$$

is well definied. I just found in the book Stochastic Differential Equations of Oksendal the follwing definition (6th edition, Page 9):

Given a probability space $(\Omega,\Sigma,P)$ and a $\Sigma$-borel-measurble function $X  \colon \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^n$ , then $\mu_X$ is  a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ definied through

$$\mu_x(B) = P(X^{-1}(B))$$.

If $\int_\Omega |X(\omega)| \, dP(\omega) < \infty$ then the number

$$\int_\Omega X(\omega) \, dP(\omega) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} x d\mu_X(x) $$

is called the expecetation value.

However, I have never heard about the case of integrating a function $X\colon \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^n $. I could only assume that in this case
$\int_\Omega X(x) \, \mu(dx)$ is a vector and $(\int_\Omega X(x) \, \mu(dx) )_i =\int_\Omega X_i(x) \, \mu(dx) $, but above it is clearly said that $\int_\Omega X(\omega) \, dP(\omega)$ is a number.

What is ment with $\int_\Omega |X(\omega)| \, dP(\omega)$? Did I miss something fundamental?

Answer (score 1):

This is a misprint and your assumption is right. When $\displaystyle\int_\Omega \|X\|\mathrm dP$ is finite (as integral of a nonnegative real-valued function), the integral $\displaystyle\int_\Omega X\mathrm dP$ exists and is the point in $\mathbb R^n$ whose $i$th entry is $\displaystyle\int_\Omega X_i\mathrm dP$.

Comment: So in total there are two misprints, the first one is that he wrote $\int_\Omega |X| dP$ instead of $\int_\Omega ||X|| dP$, and the second that he wrote number instead of vector, right? I think its very strange that the 6th edition of a almost 30 years old book that is very popular with a tons of reviewer has still such a fundamental error on page 9.

Comment: One may disagree with "fundamental error" and find that "misprint" is more adapted.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt want to offend anyone. Does also $\int_\Omega X_i(\omega) dP(\omega) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} x_i \, d\mu_X(x)$ hold? Could you give a reference to your statement? I can't find anything about this, neither on wikipedia, my pobability theory script nor on  the book pobability theory of heinz bauer.